# confused with compare and jump in assembly language?what is the correct way to fix it?

Tags: assembly, x86

some code above here............
 i want the user to enter the number 0 or 1 to select the menu,the following menu is set and alacart 
dont know why cannot compare and jump correctly

```
    cmp bufi,0
    je set
    jne wronginput


    cmp bufi,1
    je ala
    jne wronginput

set:
    lea dx, setmeal      
    call endpar
    lea dx, dotline      
    call endpar
    lea dx, menusetA         
    call endpar
    lea dx, menusetB         
    call endpar
    lea dx, menusetC         
    call endpar

    jmp oder

alac:
    lea dx, setala   
    call endpar
    lea dx, pasta    
    call endpar
    lea dx, asian   
    call endpar


 wronginput:
    lea dx, promptwronginput
    call endpar
    lea dx, nextLine
    call endpar

endpar:
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    ret
```

please leave a comment and a suggestion
and i appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others said, you must check for the ASCII values for `'0'` or `'1'`, not for the values `0` or `1`.

But you have another problem. After the corrction, you still have this:

```
    cmp bufi,'0'
    je set
    jne wronginput
```

That means that the next few lines are never reached, since if `bufi` is not `'0'`, you jump to `wronginput:` without checking for `'1'`. Remove the first conditional jump to `wronginput:` and do the following:

```
    cmp bufi,'0'
    je set
    cmp bufi,'1'
    je ala

    ; neither '0' nor '1', so wrong input
    jmp wronginput

set:
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you're filling `bufi`, but most likely it's a *character* entered by the user, so you need to test for the *characters* `'0'` or `'1'`, not the *integer values* `0` or `1`. So change:

```
cmp bufi,0
```

to:

```
cmp bufi,'0'
```

and similarly change:

```
cmp bufi,1
```

to:

```
cmp bufi,'1'
```

Answer (score 0):

well user input is an ASCII input which means that you have to compare "bufi" with the hexadecimal representation of that input ...well for 0 its 30h and 1 is 31h or you can simply compare with chars '0' or '1' .

```
cmp bufi,30h  ; for 0
```

or

```
cmp bufi,31h ; for 1
```